# Can we do anything without using Sync methods, or in some cases, we must use Sync methods in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, functional-programming, require

For instance, I have **`app.js`** to have a Module object:`M` by loading(`require`) a file:`_core.js`, then properties of `M` are to add by loading(`require`) files under a directory: `./Project_Functions/`

```
var Project_FunctionsDIR = './Project_Functions/';
var Project_coreFile = '_core.js';

var M = require(Project_FunctionsDIR + Project_coreFile);

require("fs")
  .readdir(Project_FunctionsDIR,
    function(err, files)
    {
      files.forEach(function(file)
      {
        if (file !== Project_coreFile)
        {
          var name = file.split('.js')[0]; 
          var filepath = Project_FunctionsDIR + file;
          M[name] = require(filepath); 
        }
      });
    });
console.log('module.exports');
module.exports = M;
```

Here, the constructed moduleObject:`M` is exported by `module.exports`.

Please note the `fs.readdir` is async, so `module.exports = M;` is evaluated *before* `M` properties are constructed in `app.js`.

Now, I want to test this object `M` in **`test.js`**,

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

var M = require('./app.js');
//........
```

On `var M = require('./app.js');` line, the `app.js` is evaluated, which indicates that the `M` object is exported *before* the whole properties are constructed.

In fact, I inserted `setTimeout` at the `fs.readdir` callback, the test fails obviously the `M` object is not ready yet.

Firstly, I thought `module.exports = M;` should be put within the `fs.readdir` callback, but if I do that, now `var M = require(Project_FunctionsDIR + Project_coreFile);` part fails, probably because `module.exports = M;` is not exposed to read properly.

Yes, this can be resolved simply by using `fs.readdirSync` and actually, I have been doing so when I encounter this sort of problem, however, I always feel uncomfortable to use node Sync methods and rather try to seek a smarter work-around.

So, here's my question; is it possible by not using Sync method for this issue? or impossible?

Furthermore, I'd like to ask more in general.

Can we do anything without using Sync methods, or in some cases, we must use Sync methods in `node.js`?

In functional programming scheme, Sync methods should be avoided if possible since the Sync concept depends on not function(callback) but *time*.

Thanks for your thought.

---

EDIT:

I've just found a related topic here:
[Asynchronous initialization of Node.js module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835096/asynchronous-initialization-of-node-js-module)

The conclusion is we must use Sync method to correspond a Sync method. In this case, `require` is a sync method.

Comment: you can have your test wait, or you can use sync methods. Since require itself is sync, i don't see this a cardinal sin if it's only done during boot, since that won't affect ultimate performance or capacity.

Comment: Thanks, I have another answer to suggest `require` is sync, so impossible to use async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common pattern is for the module to expose an asynchronous `initialize` method that does the asynchronous work.  For your module, it would look like this:

```
var Project_FunctionsDIR = './Project_Functions/';
var Project_coreFile = '_core.js';

var M = require(Project_FunctionsDIR + Project_coreFile);

M.initialize = function(next) {
  require("fs")
  .readdir(Project_FunctionsDIR,
    function(err, files)
    {
      files.forEach(function(file)
      {
        if (file !== Project_coreFile)
        {
          var name = file.split('.js')[0]; 
          var filepath = Project_FunctionsDIR + file;
          M[name] = require(filepath); 
        }
      });
      next();
    });
}
module.exports = M;
```

Then you can test it with:

```
var M = require('./app.js');
M.initialize(function() {
  //........
}
```

This is a useful pattern because many asynchronous methods don't have synchronous versions, and it allows you to run many of these asynchronous `initialize`s in parallel, drastically reducing startup time for larger apps.

Comment: I understand the principle completely thanks to you. This is surely very promising, but for strange unknown reason, I could not reach the callback from `fs.readdir` in `test.js` file.. I could invoke whole from the same `app.js` file by calling `initialize(...)`, so I'm investigating now.

Comment: Ok, it's an async issue of the testing framework(Mocha), this is the great way to deal with sync method with async. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

node.js uses CommonJS module pattern, which by definition export their exposed objects synchronously on load. What you're trying to do is not possible asynchronously, although you can do it just by exposing the other files into your 'main' export. If you want to dynamically expose all files in a directory from one object, just use the synchronous readdir, it'll only be executed on start up.

Comment: Thanks, I confirmed that. I will edit my Q with a related topic I've just found.

Comment: What you can do is expose an object (module.exports = anObj), and asynchronously populate that object in your async readdir. And those properties are available elsewhere. But then you don't know when those properties exist elsewhere, other than doing setTimeout checks and waiting. This is ugly and a huge bad code smell, though.

Comment: All right, basically I would give up to stick to async for such a sync method `require`. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. I've got a good alternative solution here, so I switched the Check, sorry for that.